# Google Cloud Vision TEXT_DETECTION only on digits

Tags: machine-learning, computer-vision, google-cloud-vision

Is there any way to constrain google cloud vision, especially for type TEXT_DETECTION to only recognize digits? I think it will greatly improve my result.

I cannot find any result or hint on the internet at all. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Currently we are unable to constrain by numbers alone. HAve you tried the updated response stream with granular polyboxes to see if this is still an issue?