# How to change the recognition language

Tags: python, ocr, google-cloud-vision

Using Google vision from [here](https://github.com/googlecloudplatform/google-cloud-python) I was successfully able to create a `client` and an `image` using `vision.Client()` and `client.image(content=data)` respectively. And then send my image using `image.detect_text()`, attempting to read the digits within the image. however Google-vision has been inaccurate and I heard, from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39540741/google-cloud-vision-numbers-and-numerals-ocr) question, that by setting the language to another (non-latin) language would help with this.

But that is where I am stuck, I'm not sure where to set the `languageHints`, and yes I have seen [this](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/reference/rest/v1/images/annotate#AnnotateImageRequest) link to the documentation of the `AnnotateImageRequest`, but I am still confused as to where this comes in.

Answer (score 6):

I am not an expert in this but the following seems to work for me:

First you create an image_context object, as follows:

```
image_context = types.ImageContext(language_hints =["en"])
```

Then you call  text_detection with the image_context you created as parameter, as follows:

```
 response = client.text_detection(image=image, image_context=image_context)
```

Answer (score 0):

image_context = vision.ImageContext(language_hints =["en"])
response = client.text_detection(image=image, image_context=image_context)

Comment: As it's currently written, your answer might be correct but it could be improved in 2 ways. First and foremost, it helps to format code as code. This makes it more readable. Second, some supporting text might help to let the OP know that you understood the question thouroughly. Hope this helps!